# how get object from main ROT in windows service

Tags: windows-services

I have my c# windows service (local system). From service i'm try to get running PowerPoint 
Object pp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject('PowerPoint.Application');
pp - is always null, and count objects of ROT is also null.
How connect to main ROT from windows service (probably "WinSta0")?
Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

you might need the interact with desktop privilage. (also have you seen [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316125)? , i konw your not getting an error, but still )

- also stumbled apon [this](http://www.ureader.com/msg/14781331.aspx) thread, that sais that ROT registration is user context sensitive by default.